# unresolved external symbol(all symbols are defined!)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm  getting an error  **LNK2001    unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Game::Draw(void)"**

for my Game constructor, my Update function, and my Draw function, I have cleaned/rebuilt and all my libraries are linked properly, my symbols are defined, and I don't have any circular include paths, does anyone know what's causing this?

Edit: I nuked the .vs folder and it has the same error but for a different class

**Game.H:**

```
class Game {
public:

    Game(int internalWidth, int internalHeight, int windowWidth, int windowHeight);
    Game();

    void Update();
    void Draw();


};
```

**Game.cpp:**

```
void Game::Update() {
    /*Spaghetti code */

}

Game::Game(int internalWidth, int internalHeight, int windowWidth, int windowHeight) {
    /*Spaghetti code */
}

void Game::Draw() {
    /*Spaghetti code */

}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
    Game game(1024, 768, 1024, 768);
    bool running = true;


    while (running) {
        game.Update();
        game.Draw();
    }
```

Comment: You declare a second constructor `Game();` but never define it. however, `void Game::Draw()` is reported missing, but exists, so either the error message is wrong, or the linker is called incorrectly.

Comment: Most likely, your build configuration doesn't actually result in `Game.cpp` being compiled or linked in.

Comment: Or you edited `game.cpp` to add the definition of `Game::Draw` but didn't save the file before compiling.

Comment: @Aganju yeah I nuked the .vs folder and it showed the same error but for a different class so it's probably an incorrect error message :/